# Is there some sort of periodicity in the gauge which is responsible for particle number discretization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, discrete

I have been thinking about how periodicity in a physical parameter is related to the discretization of its canonical conjugate, much like the periodicity in time results in the discretization of the Fourier frecuencies.

For example, the periodicity in the angle parameter results in the discretization of angular momentum spectrum. The periodic space boundary conditions result in the discretization of linear momentum. The periodic classical motion of a bounded state results in the discretization of energy values. And so on.

Furthermore, there is a certain periodicity in the application of space-time inversion and particle exchange. When you apply the corresponding operators twice, you get back to the original wavefunction. These also result in the discretization of physical variables, namely parity and exchange symmetry.

I was wondering if there is some type of gauge periodicity which might be held accountable for occupation number discretization. I assumed that the gauge and the occupation number were sort of "conjugate", as the symmetry in the gauge usually results in matter conservation laws, much like the symmetry in the angle results in angular momentum conservation.

Is it simply the phase periodicity which accounts for this? Or is there something more?

Comment: In which theory? What gauge?